# Why screen dimension doesn't equals weight

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

Why screen width divided by 7 is not equal to one part of layout which has `weight=1` when layout `weightSum=7`? How can I count how many `dp/px` equals this weight in Java code?

Comment: Post your layout. There could be margins or padding, or items without weight. Also show how you determine view and screen width.

Comment: `Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;` This is how I get width. Layout is just LinearLayout with 7 ImageView inside. But how can I get any margins or padding, even if they exist, when I'm doing this inside fragment and there is life cycle problem?

Comment: You must have **7** Views with `weight=1` to make your single View width measure **1/7th** of the screen width (excluding eventual container paddings/margins). And **ONLY** if the container is a LinearLayout. And **ONLY** if the Views width is **0dp**.